# Android Repeating Alarm Manager not Fired

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I have been using the following code to set fire an alarm every 20 seconds

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String APP_TAG = "LOG: ";


private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class); 
    PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            now.getTimeInMillis(), EXEC_INTERVAL, intentExecuted);
}
```

}

The code works as expected and I receive my log message every 20 seconds in LogCat.

I would like to set a daily repeating alarm to fire at 10:00AM every day. However the alarm is not fired. I have changed the time in my emulator before 10:00AM (e.g. 9.59AM) and then run the code. However the alarm is not fired at 10:00AM. I have also set an id for the alarm. I have also changed the date in the emulator to tomorrow. No alarms are fired at all.

Any reasons as to why this is the case?

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String APP_TAG = "LOG: ";
private static final int ALARM_ID_2000 = 2000;

//private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class);       
    PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, ALARM_ID_2000, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Calendar updateTime = new GregorianCalendar();
    //we want to set a daily alarm at 10:00AM
    updateTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.DATE,cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH,cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intentExecuted);
}
```

I have switched back to my old code and now im still not getting the alarms fired on boot. I have tried the following:

1. Kill ADB
2. Restart eclipse
3. New emulator

This was working with the 20 second alarm yesterday, but now even that code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the code but the emulator. The process was not showing for the app under the devices view. I was expecting the alarms to fire when the emulator first starts, however I had to reboot the emulator i.e. turning the device on and off from the emulator window in order to mimick a reboot.

Once the emulator "rebooted" then the alarms fire as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String APP_TAG = "LOG: ";
private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class); 
PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        now.getTimeInMillis(), EXEC_INTERVAL, intentExecuted);
}
}
```

All I have changed here is I have added now.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); to retrieve current time.
Also ensure you have added the receiver in manifest.